# Including a package and make eclipse-project

Tags: ros, package, eclipse, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm having some troubles with make eclipse-project, I've developed a ros package and now I want to use it in other package, I add the dependency to the manifest.xml but when I run make eclipse-project it doesn't appear in the list of eclipse includes.

Am I missing some steps? I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34276/including-a-package-and-make-eclipse-project/) by [SergioGutierrez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2305/sergiogutierrez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the error, I forgot the export tag of the manifest I want to use, now works correctly.

---

Originally posted by [SergioGutierrez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2305/sergiogutierrez/) with karma: 86 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1